# iOS handleOpenURL with Phonegap 1.6.0

Tags: ios, ios5, cordova

Cordova: 1.6.0

iOS: 5.1

XCode: 4.3.1

I'm trying to tap into the handleOpenURL in Phonegap 1.6.0 with a very basic example program.  I'd like to analyze a url every time a http/https request is made.  All I have done right now is add a log message to see the host of the url.

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application handleOpenURL: 
(NSURL*)url 
{ 
    NSLog(@"Hi"); 
    NSLog(@"Host: %@", [url host]);

    if (!url) { 
        return NO; 
    }

    ... 
}
```

However, the log message never writes anything to the console.

I did notice the comment:

```
// only valid if Example-Info.plist specifies a protocol to handle
```

Perhaps my Example-Info.plist file is wrong?  I've added the CFBundleURLTypes to it, assuming that's what it means by "specify a  protocol to handle".  Do I have to add something else somewhere?  Below is the example section of my Example-Info.plist file.  Is it possible the simulator is not recognizing my .plist modifications?

```
... 
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key> 
<array> 
    <dict> 
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key> 
            <array> 
                <string>http</string>
                <string>https</string> 
            </array> 
    </dict> 
</array>
```

I've also implmeneted, since handleOpenURL is deprecated.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication (NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    NSLog(@"Hi");
    ...
}
```

Neither are getting called as I open URLs in my application.  I've tried all the solutions in stack-overflow, with no such luck.  If it is any help, I'm using jQuery mobile 1.1.0 for page transitions.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the purpose of those methods. They are to deal with the URLs used to **open** your app not any URLs you open in a UIWebView.

You should be looking at the delegate methods for [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Specifically

`- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`

Comment: That certainly did help, thanks @koregan.  The main problem was that they changed where we should be overriding these methods since Cordova 1.5.0.

For future reference, as of Cordova 1.6.0... you should be modifying the methods in **MainViewController.m** and not **AppDelegate.m**